# Fetch some data from webpage And store the datas into json file using php or node.js

Tags: php, html, json

i input some phone number on http://www.dndstatus.com/dnd-check-process.php
and after submiting it shows details like DND status,network operator and Telecom Circle.
I want to fetch these details from the resulting webpage (http://www.dndstatus.com/dnd-check-process.php?num=9721395967) and store to a json file.
How can i do that??

Comment: PHP's cURL should be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /* gets the data from a URL */
    function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
$strDetails = get_data("http://www.dndstatus.com/dnd-check-process.php?num=9721395967");
```

Alternatively, you can use the `file_get_contents` function remotely, but many hosts don't allow this.